# How can I remove an image file that freezes my computer each time I interact with it?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, images, freeze

There is an image file that I just can't seem to get rid of no matter how hard I try.  If I click on it, try to delete it, right-click on it, try to open it up, etc., it freezes my computer and I'm forced to shut it down and turn it back on again.  I tried to see if I could somehow use my virus/anti-spyware software to scan the file in the hopes I could quarantine it and get rid of it in that manner, and nothing happened.

Please, please help me out.  I really don't know what to do in order to get rid of this file.  It's really troublesome. :(

Comment: have you tried using the command prompt to delete the file?

Answer (score 1):

Use Command Prompt to delete the file.

```
DEL /F /S /Q /A "Full Path of File with extension"
```

Substitute Full Path of File with extension within quotes above with your file's full path and name with the extension included within quotes instead.

For example, if I wanted to delete a image file named File with the file extension .iso on my desktop, I would type this command below.

```
DEL /F /S /Q /A "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\File.iso"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to safe boot and delete the file from command prompt. Use `del "filepath"` command